# what is middleware in android?

Tags: android, middleware

Wikipedia says "Anything between the kernel and the applications is known as middleware". Now, if we look at the android architecture, it consists of:

1. Applications
2. Application Framework
3. Libraries and Runtime
4. Linux kernel

so, my simple question is what is middleware in case of android architecture? Is it Libraries+Runtime or is it Libraries+Runtime+Application Framework. I read somewhere that it consists of Libraries and Runtime. If that's true then why Application Framework is not considered as a part of middleware, because according to the middleware's definition, Application Framework is also between kernel and user applications.

Comment: wikipedia is not universal truth

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it's either:

- Application Framework and
- Libraries and Runtime

Or:

- Libraries and Runtime

I would not say there is only one right opinion, this is a question of interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its the Libraries and Runtime together.

Answer (score 1):

As middle-ware is the interface between the applications and operating system.
In Android- kernel is operating system and app+app framework is applications.
Then Libraries and Android Runtime together is said to be middle-ware as per my analysis.please correct me if I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

In computer science, definitions and later categorization of components to those definitions are sometimes hazy.  There is no perfect bucketing of components :-)

Middleware: In practice, these are set of libraries that make it convenient for programmers to access OS or hardware primitives.

In Android, the libraries definitely form middleware.  I would not classify the Runtime(read virtual machine) as a middleware.

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, **Middleware** in Android development, using [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) approach, is a program layer for *asynchronous tasks, their managing, scheduling and subscribing*. You use it for *API requests, logs, analytics, persistence, other time-consuming operations* that you want to execute on a separate thread (to free-up the UI Thread, for example).

[ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io) is a popular **Middleware** library and approach you can use in your project. Its Android framework is [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid).